# question of empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1. $0\in\{\emptyset\}$
2. $\emptyset\in\{0\}$
3. $\{0\}\subset\emptyset$
4. $\{0\}\in\{0\}$
5. $\{0\}\subset\{0\}$

I think the answers of the above questions are F, F, F, T, F. Is it wrong?

Comment: It’s wrong.${}$

Comment: That actually depends on your set-theoretic implementation of “$0$” and “$\subset$”. Is “$\subset$” the same as “$\subseteq$”? If so and using [Von Neumann Ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#von_Neumann_ordinals) (where $0 = ∅$), you have for instance *True, True, False, False, True*. Not gonna do all four cases, though …

Comment: Just because it is an elementary question, it does not deserves downvotes...

Comment: @Alvaro: it didn’t receive downvotes because it’s an elementary question. It received downvotes because it is a PSQ.

Comment: @Clayton what's the meaning of "PSQ"?

Answer (score 1):

$\in$ means is an element of, $\subset$ means is a subset of. So, for example, $$
1 \in \{1,2,3\}
$$
is true, and so is $$
\{1\} \subset \{1,2,3\}
$$
but $$
\{1\} \in \{1,2,3\}
$$
is not, because none of the elements of $\{1,2,3\}$ are $\{1\}$. Note that $\{1\}$ and $1$ are not the same thing.

One sometimes confusing aspect of this notation is that $\subset$ is unlike $<$ in that $A\subset B$ doesn't imply $A\ne B$. For example, $$
\{1,2,3\} \subset \{1,2,3\}
$$
is true.

The empty set is the set with no elements. Therefore, it is never true that $a\in \emptyset$, and it is always true that $\emptyset\subset A$ for any set $A$. $A\subset \emptyset$ if and only if $A = \emptyset$.

With these facts in mind, you can see that the first three are false. The fourth one says $\{0\}$ is an element of $\{0\}$. The fifth says $\{0\}$ is a subset of $\{0\}$. Can you see where you went wrong by comparison to my examples above?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this question is given in the context of elementary math and we don't care about the exact formal meaning of the symbol "$0$" as pointed out in the comments:

1. The forth one is false, since the set $\{0\}$ is not an element of itself. Instead, $0$ is an element of the set $\{0\}$.
2. If the symbol "$\subset$" means "it is contained by or is equal to", then, the fifth is true, since $\{0\}$ and $\{0\}$ are obviously the same set. It would be false if "$\subset$" means "it is strictly contained by", since there must be some element if the right hand side set wich is not in the left hand side one.